ImGUI вызывает неправильное отображение Viewport при включении в рендеринг
Я интегрирую ImGUI в свой рендерер и столкнулся с проблемой отображения Viewport. Когда ImGUI отключен, рендерер работает корректно, и изображение растягивается на весь экран. Однако при включении ImGUI Viewport не растягивается на весь экран, и появляются артефакты.
ImGui::CreateContext();
ImGui_ImplWin32_Init(hwnd);
ImGui_ImplDX11_Init(device, deviceContext);

Что я делаю:

Передаю HWND в ImGUI для инициализации.
Рендерер работает нормально без ImGUI.
При включении ImGUI Viewport не занимает весь экран, и появляются визуальные артефакты.

Что я пробовал:

Проверял, что HWND передается корректно.

Убедился, что размеры окна и Viewport обновляются при изменении размеров окна.

Отключал ImGUI, чтобы убедиться, что проблема связана именно с ним.


Ожидаемый результат:
Viewport должен растягиваться на весь экран, как это происходит без ImGUI.
Фактический результат:
Viewport не растягивается на весь экран, и появляются артефакты.
Вопрос:
Что может быть причиной такого поведения? Как правильно настроить ImGUI, чтобы Viewport занимал весь экран и не вызывал артефактов?

